# Laravel 5.5 resource controller misbehaving

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I have my UserController created using **--resource** command.

Now, I have two routes.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');

Route::get('user/certificate', 'UserController@showUserCertificate');
```

Since I did not use **Route::resource** method, the official documentation says calling the second route should not trigger 1st one. But that's not happening in my case.

OD also says in case of the order, any route rather than resource should be declared before those. I tried that too. It still takes me to **show** method instead of **showUserCertificate** method. What am I missing here?

Comment: what EXACT version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.5, php version 7.1.8

Comment: what version of 5.5. exactly what version

Comment: sorry. its 5.5.7

Comment: you need to upgrade, check my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofcourse it is always hitting the `show` route. It is the first route that matches the URI you are requesting ... you have a route parameter defined in that route so it matches anything starting with `user` and having 1 additional segment.

```
user/blah
user/anything
user/certificate
```

All of those match `user/{id}`. The first route to match is the one that is used. Reverse the order of those two routes so the more specific one is first.

**Update:**
You need to upgrade the framework. There was a bug introduced in that exact version related to route sorting. 5.5.8 fixes it. [Reference to GitHub PR to revert change](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21261)

Comment: Sorry I probably failed to explain in the 2nd paragraph. I tried declaring user/{id} after declaring user/certificate. Still, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: well i can't guess at all the routes you have defined in your application ... this is how routing works, first route that matches gets used, it never changes ... you shouldn't have your routes cached but clear the route cache incase

Comment: tried clearing route cache, didn't help. And 'user/{id}' is the only route that's causing the problem. There are no other routes that can cause such thing.

Answer (score 0):

yes in this scenario the first route will be called every time you call the second route.
the certificate in the second route will be considered as {id} in the first controller. vote my answer if it is correct

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');

Route::get('user/certificate', 'UserController@showUserCertificate');
```

//you can change it to 
Route::get('user/certificate/{id}', 'UserController@showUserCertificate');

Comment: Sorry I probably failed to explain in the 2nd paragraph. I tried declaring user/{id} after declaring user/certificate. Still, it didn't solve the problem.